# How can I fix (or ignore) javascript errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution whose startup project is an ASP.NET website (the kind **without** a .vbproj file)

When I'm running in debug mode, the first error I get is a popup

```
Unhandled exception at line 539, column 51 in script block

0x800a138a - JavaScript runtime error: Function expected
```

The code "file" is called "script block [dyanmic]" so I think this js is being created by VS or it's a third party code, which means I probably can't fix it.  This bold portion of the code below was in yellow when I did a "break".  (sorry, I don't know how to highlight a portion of a code block in stack overflow)

function LPCTR(a){var b=0;if("undefined"!=typeof g**_isdebug&&g_isdebug||"undefined"!=typeof debug&&debug)init_LPctr(),b=LPc**tr.increment(a);return 0!==b}

I'm getting several errors similar to this.

1. How can I ignore these errors?.  There is an "exception settings" window in the IDE, and I have "JavaScript Runtime Exceptions" completely unchecked.  (My site appears to be working otherwise)
2. How can I find the "owner" of this code?  I don't have a LPCTR function.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the eror window and at the bottom select to clear javascript errors. They are gone and will not appear next time you compile your project.

Answer (score -1):

Put the code in a try-catchblock

```
try {
  // Your code here
} catch(e) {
  // Code run on error, with info var e
}
```

Comment: He's not even sure how that code is ending up on a page, so how could he add a try/catch around it?

Comment: He said "How can I ignore these errors?". This could be around the third-party code calling the code causing the error